# VScode Software - No leftsidebar menu visible

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to VScode software.

I have installed it , but it seems that every example i see on the net has a leftsidebarmenu.
[Example of vertical menu bar here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFSA7.png)

But my vscode 2022 on windows does not have it.
[My vscode 2022 without vertical leftbar menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TBIo.png)

Anyone how i can add it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: View -> Appearance -> Show Primary Sidebar (Ctrl/Cmd+B) or View -> Appearance -> Show Activity Bar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its not Visual Studio Code, you have downloaded Visual Studio, thats an IDE

You can download it here -> [Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to View in Menu Bar and then Select Appearance the Tick the option Show Activity Bar

Comment: Also You are not using VS CODE it is Visual Studio Please vs Code